# Is it possible to remove UISearchBar's tint image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i have to hide searchbar tint.
 i write foll0wing  code

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 15, 270, 15)];
searchBar.delegate = self;
searchBar.barStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
searchBar.placeholder =@"search";
searchBar.tintColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[imageview addSubview:searchBar];
```

here search bar add on imageview. i want to hide tint side but bydeaflt it comes .i also chage the color to tint color but it not work.is anybody  have idea of removing or hide tint on searchbar .Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps.

```
[searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
```

Will also work in iOS 7.1

Answer (score 2):

I have used this code. It completely removed the tint around the search text bar.

```
for (id v in [self.search subviews]) {
        if (![v isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarTextField")]) {
            [v setAlpha:0.0f];
            [v setHidden:YES];
        }
        else {
            [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I customized the UISearchBar

```
if ([[[searchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
    [[[searchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

This removes the background bar style.

You can then add any custom subview you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[searchBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

Also, don't set the tintColor when using translucent

Comment: i try above syntax in code .alse not set tint color but still tint come on both side.is tint come bydefault